# How to open/unlock the BMA 2215 cable box for connecting a ceiling lamp?

Tags: tools, cables, lamp

I was going to install a newly bought ceiling lamp when I found this connection box which I have never seen before. It has "BMA 2215" written on it and an internet search led to websites selling it, but I cannot find instructions on how to open it.

It is quite clear how it is constructed, with a lid and 4 "hooks" that stick in place when closed. But I haven't been able to open it, after trying with various sharp tools. It seems like it requires a special made tool to open, which was not included with the lamp.

It was closed to 3/4 out of the box, but I suspect it was supposed to be unlocked, so that it would be possible to connect the cables and then close it. It does not make sense that it is already closed without cables connected.

The black plastic cover that connects to the lamp has electric cables inside, as expected, but the other black plastic has nothing inside, as this is where the ceiling cables need to be inserted.

Edit: The plastic isn't very strong, so it would be easy to force open it with a screwdriver, but I think that would also break the cable box and render it useless.

https://www.mpm.fr/produit.php?langue=en&id=168

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably the only special tool needed is having three hands.  Most people only have two hands and these boxes are difficult to open with just two.  A small flat blade tool(screwdriver like) to push tabs in while pulling top apart should do it.  But be careful not use to much force.

Comment: Or just take it back to where you bought it... as delivered, it's not fit for purpose.

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you connect the plug, shown, to the terminal block shown?  Is there supposed to be an electrical outlet inside the canopy?  And the lamp hangs from the terminal block that is supposed to be attached to the ceiling?  All of that inside the little plastic canopy?  Or is there meant to be a cable installed that routes from the terminal block to an electrical outlet somewhere else?  How is that cable meant to exit the canopy?  There is no cutout for it.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem here, at least for me, is that it intuitively feels natural to try to press the round "buttons" inwards, to release. However, once you see one open (a catch 22, since this is what you have problems to achieve), it is clear that those are not the kind of buttons you can compress, since they are rigid parts of the box.

[image: box, once finally opened]

Instead, it is the "loop" (in lack of a better word) that hold around the buttons, that should be lifted.

By fitting a tiny flat screw driver, underneath the loop, and gently twist it, you will hopefully be able to release it. (Like described in the previous answer.)

Answer (score 1):

One corner is already open.  If you open the adjacent one, the other side should open like a door.  So you only have to pry one tab open.  I would use a tiny screwdriver and just pry it here:

[image]

If that didn't work I would break it open and put it back together with zip ties, or just cut the entire annoying thing off and go buy another connector ... a terminal block or wagos or whatever or just rewire the whole lamp starting at the bulb socket, with a sufficiently long cable not needing a connector there.

[image]
[image]

I don't know how I would attach this thing to the ceiling if I chopped off this block and replaced it with something else.  But on the assumption that this entire lamp hangs from the ceiling by the two little plastic screw holes in this crappy connector block, you could hardly do worse.  Drive a screw hook into the ceiling and string said zip ties through it or if you rewire the lamp, just tie the cable to the hook. Done.